# How to call servlet when deploying Java EE project

Tags: servlets, jakarta-ee

I am new to Java EE. I am  developing a web application project using Java EE. My question is I have call the Servlet when the project is deploying.

Can any one say how to call the Servlet so that I can run a Servlet while deploying the project?

Answer (score 0):

Just put the code which you'd like to execute during servlet initialization in servlet's [`init()`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/GenericServlet.html#init%28%29) method.